# Nested mysql query over 3 tables does not show the correct result

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a nested query.
There are 3 tables
gutschriften_products, orders_products , products

*Query*

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gutschriften_products` (
  `gut_orders_products_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gut_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `orders_products_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `products_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `products_price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `final_price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `products_quantity` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`gut_orders_products_id`)
) ;

INSERT INTO `gutschriften_products` (`gut_orders_products_id`, `gut_id`, `orders_products_id`, `orders_id`, `products_id`, `products_name`, `products_price`, `final_price`, `products_quantity`) VALUES
(1, 1, 12, 108, 375, 'Prod 375', '92.3529', '92.3529', 1),
(2, 2, 13, 109, 375, 'Prod 375', '65.9664', '65.9664', 1),
(3, 3, 51, 110, 377, 'Prod 377', '71.8487', '71.8487', 1),
(4, 4, 40, 111, 432, 'Prod 432', '82.7731', '82.7731', 1),
(5, 4, 41, 112, 427, 'Prod 427', '72.6891', '72.6891', 1),
(6, 4, 42, 113, 420, 'Prod 420', '72.6891', '72.6891', 1),
(7, 4, 43, 114, 423, 'Prod 423', '82.7731', '82.7731', 1),
(8, 4, 44, 115, 423, 'Prod 423', '82.7731', '82.7731', 1),
(9, 5, 59, 116, 451, 'Prod 451', '78.5714', '78.5714', 1);
```

====

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders_products` (
  `orders_products_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `products_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `products_price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `final_price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `products_quantity` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`orders_products_id`),
  KEY `orders_id` (`orders_id`),
  KEY `orders_id_2` (`orders_id`),
  KEY `products_id` (`products_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `orders_products` (`orders_products_id`, `orders_id`, `products_id`, `products_name`, `products_price`, `final_price`, `products_quantity`) VALUES
(12, 108, 375, 'Prod 375', '100.7563', '100.7563', 1),
(13, 109, 375, 'Prod 375', '78.5714', '78.5714', 1),
(14, 110, 376, 'Prod 376', '70.1681', '70.1681', 1),
(15, 111, 377, 'Prod 377', '63.0252', '63.0252', 1),
(16, 112, 376, 'Prod 376', '70.1681', '70.1681', 1),
(17, 113, 377, 'Prod 377', '92.3529', '92.3529', 1),
(18, 114, 375, 'Prod 375', '69.3277', '69.3277', 1),
(19, 115, 376, 'Prod 376', '117.5600', '117.5600', 1),
(20, 116, 377, 'Prod 377', '79.8319', '79.8319', 1);
```

====

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `products_quantity` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `products_price` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `products_date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `products_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `manufacturers_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `products_ordered` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `products_ek` double(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `products_verfuegbar` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `products_geprueft` datetime NOT NULL,
  `products_lagernd` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`),
  KEY `idx_products_date_added` (`products_date_added`)
) ;

INSERT INTO `products` (`products_id`, `products_quantity`, `products_price`, `products_date_added`, `products_status`, `manufacturers_id`, `products_ordered`, `products_ek`, `products_verfuegbar`, `products_geprueft`, `products_lagernd`) VALUES
(375, 18, '71.00840336', '2015-05-04 17:44:45', 1, 16, 75, 41.00000000, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0),
(376, 10, '77.73109244', '2015-05-05 10:28:31', 1, 16, 67, 45.00000000, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0),
(377, 10, '71.00840336', '2015-05-05 10:45:08', 1, 16, 52, 41.00000000, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0),
(378, 8, '71.00840336', '2015-05-05 10:52:20', 1, 16, 35, 41.00000000, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0),
(379, 10, '77.73109244', '2015-05-05 10:56:47', 1, 16, 36, 45.00000000, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0);
```

I want to find out which items are sold / returned how often. Unfortunately, my approach only prints those items that have been sold AND returned. Items that have NEVER been sold or returned will not be displayed.

```
SELECT
(verkauft - gutschrift)*(P.products_price - products_ek) / (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), P.products_date_added))*365 AS GEZE,
   DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), P.products_date_added) AS dtage,
   products_quantity,
   DATE_FORMAT(P.products_date_added, " % d. % m. % Y") AS hinzu,
   P.products_date_added,
   A.products_id,
   A.products_name,
   verkauft,
   gutschrift,
   final_price,
   verkauft - gutschrift AS summe,
   gutschrift / verkauft*100 AS rquote,
   products_ek AS EK,
   P.products_price AS VK,
   P.products_date_added AS aufgenommen,
   P.manufacturers_id,
   (
      verkauft - gutschrift
   )
   *(P.products_price - products_ek) AS gewinn,
   products_lagernd 
FROM
   (
      select
         products_id,
         products_name,
         sum(products_quantity) as verkauft 
      from
         orders_products 
      where
         orders_id BETWEEN 1 AND 11847 
      group by
         products_id
   )
   AS A 
   JOIN
      (
         select
            final_price,
            products_id,
            products_name,
            sum(products_quantity) as gutschrift 
         from
            gutschriften_products 
         where
            final_price > 0 
            AND orders_id BETWEEN 1 AND 11847 
         group by
            products_id
      )
      AS B 
      ON A.products_id = B.products_id 
   JOIN
      (
         select
            products_geprueft,
            products_id,
            products_status,
            manufacturers_id,
            products_quantity,
            products_ek,
            products_price,
            products_lagernd,
            products_date_added 
         from
            products
      )
      AS P 
      ON P.products_id = B.products_id 
where
   products_status > 0 
   AND 1 = 1 
order by
   products_name ASC,
   products_id
```

Result:
There are only two rows with product_id = 375 and 377

But I have 3 other products 376, 378, 379
Why aren't they listed?

Comment: Are you aware you are using GROUP BY in a invalid way?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed66a0/5 .. "Result: There are only two rows with product_id = 375 and 377" You really can **not** trust the data in your current output because you misused MySQL's extended GROUP BY "feature".. So you need to provide a formatted text table what results you would expect based on the example data.

Answer (score 0):

I know I shouldn't do this but I'm a bit board so.... (please compare it to your original sql and reach conclusions)

```
    SELECT
  (verkauft - gutschrift)*(P.products_price - products_ek) / (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), P.products_date_added))*365 AS GEZE,
   DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), P.products_date_added) AS dtage,
   P.products_quantity,
   DATE_FORMAT(P.products_date_added, "%d.%m.%Y") AS hinzu,
   P.products_date_added,
   P.products_id,
   A.products_name,
   verkauft,
   gutschrift,
   final_price,
   verkauft - gutschrift AS summe,
   gutschrift / verkauft*100 AS rquote,
   products_ek AS EK,
   P.products_price AS VK,
   P.products_date_added AS aufgenommen,
   P.manufacturers_id,
   (verkauft - gutschrift ) *(P.products_price - products_ek) AS gewinn, 
   products_lagernd 
FROM products P
LEFT JOIN ( select
             products_id,
             products_name,
             sum(products_quantity) as verkauft 
            from orders_products 
            where orders_id BETWEEN 1 AND 11847 
            group by products_id ) AS A ON P.products_id = A.products_id
LEFT JOIN (select
              final_price,
              products_id,
              products_name,
              sum(products_quantity) as gutschrift 
           from gutschriften_products 
           where final_price > 0 AND orders_id BETWEEN 1 AND 11847 
           group by products_id ) AS B ON A.products_id = B.products_id    
where products_status > 0    
order by products_name ASC, products_id;
```

please reply if it's good for you...